# How can I 'Horizontalize' a second query into my first query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem that can be simulated with a system much like SO's: posts and tags. To get my posts, I might do something like this:

```
SELECT title, body, author FROM posts WHERE id = ?
```

And then get my tags very simply

```
SELECT tag_id FROM tags_on_posts WHERE post_id = ?
```

Let's say I have a limit like SO does where you can only have 5 tags per post. Is there anyway I can do this in a single query?

```
SELECT title, body, author, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5 
  FROM posts 
  JOIN /*help*/ 
  WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: [Have you tried a SQL Pivot?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) they can be painful but are super useful. [You can also be dynamic with them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: I neglected my database specific tag. I'm working on Postgres. Now that I know the term PIVOT, I've just opened up a new research avenue.

Comment: Ahh, well I hope those avenues help. If you know it will always be 5... you could just use temporary table to construct the two intermediary tables and then merge them into a third final one.

Comment: Several fixes in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate the tags into a string and split them at the application side

```
select
    title, body, author,
    string_agg(tag_id, ',') as tag_ids
from
    posts p
    inner join
    tags_on_posts top on p.id = top.post_id
where p.id = ?
group by 1, 2, 3
```

If the tag names are in a third table

```
select
    title, body, author,
    string_agg(tag_name, ',') as tag_names
from
    posts p
    inner join
    tags_on_posts top on p.id = top.post_id
    inner join
    tags t on t.id = top.tag_id
where p.id = ?
group by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: `string_Agg` takes a second parameter as a delimiter as well, this may very well be a great solution if there are characters that are black listed from tags.

Comment: IF I had a quarter for every forgotten parameter I could pay off my soda debt to the fridge around here.

Comment: what is "group by 1, 2, 3" - I get group by, but what exactly is 1 2 3 here?

Comment: @corsiKa The columns by order in the select list.